# Where is lambda bootstrap log location

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Where (or how) to check for lambda bootstrap script log statements?

For example, if I have an example of the following bootstrap script where can i see date, echo statement?

```
#!/bin/sh
cd $LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT
date
echo 'post date'
```

Comment: AWS Lambda does not support User Data scripts. Can you show more details about how you have implemented this code?

Comment: @John, I was trying custom runtime as described in the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/runtimes-custom.html) just replaced, node with date and did not see the date or echo statement in cloudwatch log.

Comment: User error, I was mixing custom runtime with python.  I can see logging in CloudWatch log.